# WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value php

Tags: php, redis

Hi I am using Laravel with Redis .When I am trying to access a key by get method then get following error "WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value"

I am using following code to access the key value -

i use this code for get data from redis

```
$values = "l_messages";
$value = $redis->HGETALL($values);
print($value);
```

Answer (score 934, accepted):

Redis supports 6 data types. You need to know what type of value that a key maps to, as for each data type, the command to retrieve it is different.

Here are the commands to retrieve key value(s):

- if value is of type string -> GET `<key>`
- if value is of type hash -> HGET or HMGET or HGETALL `<key>`
- if value is of type lists -> lrange `<key> <start> <end>`
- if value is of type sets -> smembers `<key>`
- if value is of type sorted sets -> ZRANGEBYSCORE `<key> <min> <max>`
- if value is of type stream -> xread count `<count>` streams `<key>` `<ID>`. https://redis.io/commands/xread

Use the [`TYPE`](https://redis.io/commands/type) command to check the type of value a key is mapping to:

- type `<key>`

Comment: So when you use the methods that write/read byte[]'s directly, which of those is being used?

Comment: why I can't only use `hget` for hash type?

Comment: @alramdein you can use HGET and specify the "field in the hash stored at key". 'HGET <key> <field>' or HGETALL to see all the fields

Comment: Great answer! I don't think I have seen this explained as clearly and simply as this on the Redis website or in their documentation.

Comment: You saved my day too, thanks :). And for who is using `bullmq`, to look at jobs in a queue you should try `keys *` and `HGETALL key` to see what you sent to the queue.

Answer (score 26):

This error says that you are trying to push a wrong value into the key, which means that there already exists same key but with different data structure.

To get all the keys do this in the redis cli

```
keys *
```

This should display all the keys
Now to get the type of value the key stores, do

```
type <key>
```

so it says what value you can push into the key.
In my case the type was string (using set) and i was trying to use the key as list

Answer (score 13):

This error means that the value indexed by the key "l_messages" is not of type `hash`, but rather something else. You've probably set it to that other value earlier in your code. Try various other value-getter commands, starting with GET, to see which one works and you'll know what type is actually here.

Comment: Actually, `print($redis->TYPE($values));` will tell it to your without the guesswork ;)

Comment: Great :) Didn't know this command, never had to use it. Here's the documentation: http://redis.io/commands/type

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue when trying to set something to redis. The problem was that I previously used "set" method to set data with a certain key, like

```
$redis->set('persons', $persons)
```

Later I decided to change to "hSet" method, and I tried it this way

```
foreach($persons as $person){
    $redis->hSet('persons', $person->id, $person);
}
```

Then I got the aforementioned error. So, what I had to do is to go to redis-cli and manually delete "persons" entry with

```
del persons
```

It simply couldn't write different data structure under existing key, so I had to delete the entry and hSet then.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't PHP but I had a similar issue in C# and used this page as a reference to resolve the issue.

My .Net Core 3.1 web server's `IDistributedCache.SetStringAsync` was actually storing the data as a `hash` instead of a `string`; I confirmed this using `KeyTypeAsync`. Needless to say this was extremely confusing. It seems to be storing the configuration `DistributedCacheEntryOptions` as part of the hash with `{data}` being the sub-key of the original string.

To resolve this issue you need to read it as a hash and access the sub-key manually instead of reading it as a string. See following code:

```cs
var str = (await redisConnection.GetDatabase().HashGetAllAsync("stringKey"))?.FirstOrDefault(ele => ele.Name == "data")?.Value?.ToString();
```

EDIT: the order of the sub-hash keys is no longer consistent in recent versions of REDIS, so you can't rely on the last item being the actual data anymore. Make sure you match on `ele.Name` as above to avoid unexpected errors.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and came to find out that there was another already existing key with the same name but with different types. The already existing key was a `string` while I was expecting a `hash`.

Answer (score 0):

**WRONG DATABASE INDEX**

Sometimes it's because you are in a wrong db number. I had a same problem and changed the db to the right one, there was no problem and it worked!. I suggest you before HGETALL or whatever you want, select the correct db or at least considering which db you are in.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error by attempting to fetch a value using plain `GET` that was originally stored with `JSON.SET`. I just needed to ensure I was consistently using the correct commands.

This was in Node.js, so the fix was to go from:

```
await client.get(key);
```

To:

```
await client.json.get(key);
```