# Problem loading saved `graphdata` back into a redisgraph instance with Python

Tags: python, redis, redisgraph

I want to use redisgraph-py to load a saved graph back into a Graph object. How do I load data with redis-py that's stored as type `graphdata`?

I'm running the redisgraph docker image and have no problems seeing the graph among the keys. I'm new to redis and was trying to just use `r.get('random')` to load the saved graph but I see from the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953019/wrongtype-operation-against-a-key-holding-the-wrong-kind-of-value-php) that I need to use the right method to extract the right type of value with redis-py.

```
from io import BytesIO
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np
import redis
from redisgraph import Node, Edge, Graph

def _array2bytes(arr):
    with BytesIO() as b:
        np.save(b, arr)
        return b.getvalue()

def _bytes2array(byts):
    return np.load(BytesIO(byts))

def _add_nodes(r, graph, n_nodes):
    nodes = []
    for k in range(n_nodes):
        n = Node(label="node")
        graph.add_node(n)
        nodes.append(n)
        _id = n.alias
        feat = np.random.rand(1,100,7,7)
        feat_bytes = _array2bytes(feat)
        r.set(_id, feat_bytes)
    return nodes

def _add_edges(nodes, graph, edge_prob):
    edges = []
    for k, node0 in enumerate(nodes):
        for kk, node1 in enumerate(nodes):
            if np.random.rand() < edge_prob:
                edge = Edge(node0, "adjacent_to", node1)
                graph.add_edge(edge)
                edges.append(edge)
    return edges

def _create_random_graph(r, graphname="random", n_nodes=1000, edge_prob=0.1):
    redis_graph = Graph(graphname, r)
    nodes = _add_nodes(r, redis_graph, n_nodes)
    edges = _add_edges(nodes, redis_graph, edge_prob)
    return redis_graph

def _save_graph():
    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
    g = _create_random_graph(r)
    g.commit()
    return r

def _load_graph(r):
    # The graph is saved under the key 'random'
    print(r.type('random'))

def _main():
    r = _save_graph()
    _load_graph(r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

I'm seeing `graphdata`, and I don't know how to load this type of data using redis-py or redisgraph-py. Can't find anything in the docs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [redisgraph-py](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redisgraph-py) can't re-creating a Python graph object from a Redis key containing a graph.

To implement this the module (redisgraph-py) would have to retrieve all nodes by issuing a query:

`MATCH (n) RETURN n`

And create a redisgraph-py Node object form each, in addition it would have to issue a second query retrieving all relationships

`MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m`

And create a redisgraph-py edge object from each.

I think if we would go that way, it would make sense to implement an interface / framework similar to [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/).