# Can anyone pls help me how to resolve this issue?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

**classes.py**

```py
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, IntegerField, SubmitField

class CreateTask(Form):
    title = TextField('Task Title')
    shortdesc = TextField('Short Description')
    priority = IntegerField('Priority')
    create = SubmitField('Create')

class DeleteTask(Form):
    key = TextField('Task Key')
    title = TextField('Task Title')
    delete = SubmitField('Delete')

class UpdateTask(Form):
    key = TextField('Task Key')
    title = TextField('Task Title')
    shortdesc = TextField('Short Description')
    priority = IntegerField('Priority')
    update = SubmitField('Update')

class ResetTask(Form):
    reset = SubmitField('Reset')
```

It says -
The debugger caught an exception in your *WSGI* application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.

Comment: Please don't double-space everything. It makes it harder to read without lots of scrolling.

Comment: `validate_on_submit` is a method of `FlaskForm`, not `Form`.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience as this is my first posting here, may I know where can I make a change @Barmar?

Comment: `class CreateTask(Form):` should be `class CreateTask(FlaskForm):` and similar for the other classes.

Comment: See the example in the [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/quickstart/?highlight=validate_on_submit#validating-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from your `run.py` file, but the main issue is from `classes.py`.

In the first line of your `main()` function:

```
def main():

    # create form

    cform = CreateTask(prefix='cform')
```

You create a variable `cform` from the `CreateTask` object.

Then, further in your `main()` function, you have this if statement:

```
# response

if cform.validate_on_submit() and cform.create.data:

    return createTask(cform)
```

`cform` is a `CreateTask` object made from `flask_wtf.Form` which does not have a method `validate_on_submit()`.

I checked the [API documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/api/#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.validate_on_submit), and the `validate_on_submit()` only comes from the class `flask_wtf.FlaskForm` and not `flask_wtf.Form`

So to solve this, in your `classes.py` file:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, IntegerField, SubmitField

class CreateTask(Form):
    title = TextField('Task Title')
    shortdesc = TextField('Short Description')
    priority = IntegerField('Priority')
    create = SubmitField('Create')
```

import `FlaskForm` instead of `Form`, then update your classes to use FlaskForm -

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, IntegerField, SubmitField

class CreateTask(FlaskForm):
    title = TextField('Task Title')
    shortdesc = TextField('Short Description')
    priority = IntegerField('Priority')
    create = SubmitField('Create')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But sir even after updating the classes.py file, I'm still getting an error as - "redis.exceptions.ResponseError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value" may I know how to resolve this? ~ Thank you

Comment: That's a different error not related to this question. But if you pop that error into google, this is the first hit I get - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953019/wrongtype-operation-against-a-key-holding-the-wrong-kind-of-value-php

Comment: I was working on this for continously 6 hours and still haven't been able to solve all the errors and run, if you don't mind could you pls guide me on how to resolve this as I've uploaded my whole code of it? Would really appreciate it ~ Thank you

Comment: Working on something for a long time with no progress can be extremely frustrating - sometimes it's not bad to take a break for a bit and then come back to it. 

As for the code itself, any time you get an error, pop it into google to see if you can find the root cause of the issue like I did with your Redis error. Troubleshooting is a hard skill to develop, but will get easier as you keep working on it!